# A challenging sound-propagation problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Consider a square membrane with edge-length of L, and a circular membrane with radius R. The two membranes are fixed at the edges and are made of the same material and the fixation force at the edges is equal.
> Their eigen-angular frequencies are described respectively as: $0<\omega^¤_1<\omega^¤_2,...$ for the quadratic membrane and $0<\omega^\bullet_1<\omega^\bullet_2,...$  for the circular membrane.
>
> What is the ratio $R/L$ such that the membranes have the same lowest eigenfrequencies, that is $\omega^¤_1=\omega^\bullet_1$ ? What is the ratio $\omega^\bullet_2/\omega^¤_{2}$ for the next-lowest frequencies the value of R/L  square membrane in respect to  the circular membrane?

I set up the PDE problem

$$\Delta u=-\lambda u$$

where

$$\Delta=\bigg(\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}\bigg)$$ for the square membrane and

$$\Delta=\bigg(\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\bigg)$$ for the circular membrane

Then, for the first I get $\lambda=\frac{n\pi}{L}$ and for the second $\lambda=\frac{\alpha_{n,k}}{J_vR}^2$, ($\alpha$ are the Bessel zeros) considering the Laplace equation with Dirichlet conditions and the Bessel equation with solution for $\lambda>0$.

But from here, I am not sure how to find the answer.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by eigen-angular? eigen-functions that only depend on the radius? but what does it mean for the square?

Comment: Yes, the angular frequencies of the two operators. I have no idea what it means for the square.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong equation. We need the wave equation, not the Laplace equation here.

Let $A$ be the amplitude of oscillation of your membrane. It obeys the wave equation (WLOG taking the wave speed $c=1$),

$$\partial_t^2A-\Delta A=0 $$
We look for a normal (pure frequency) mode of oscillation, and try separation of variables. For the square membrane this is
$$A(t,x,y)=\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\omega t}X(x)Y(y)$$
Which yields
$$-\omega^2\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\omega t}X(x)Y(y)+\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\omega t}X''(x)Y(y)+\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\omega t}X(x)Y''(y)=0 \\ \omega^2=\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}+\frac{Y''(y)}{Y(y)}$$
So let
$$\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}={\lambda}^2 \\ \frac{Y''(y)}{Y(y)}={\lambda}^2 \\ \omega^2=2\lambda^2$$
And having BCs $X(0)=Y(0)=X(L)=Y(L)=0$. Clearly we get eigenfunctions and eigenvalues of the form
$$\lambda_n=\frac{n\pi}{L} \\ X_m(x)=\sin(m\pi x/L)~~,~~Y_n(y)=\sin(n\pi y/L)$$
Which gives normal frequencies for the square membrane as $$\omega^{\text{square}}_n(L)=\sqrt{2}\frac{n\pi}{L}$$

Applying the same approach to the circular membrane ($A(t,r,\theta)=\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\omega t}P(r)Q(\theta)$)gives us
$$-\omega^2\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\omega t}P(r)Q(\theta)-\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\omega t}\bigg(P''(r)Q(\theta)+\frac{1}{r}P'(r)Q(\theta)+\frac{1}{r^2}P(r)Q''(\theta)\bigg)=0 \\ r^2\frac{P''(r)}{P(r)}+r\frac{P'(r)}{P(r)}+\omega^2r^2=-\frac{Q''(\theta)}{Q(\theta)}=-\lambda^2$$
I think we have to assume no dependency on $\theta$ here, otherwise the eigenvalues can't be ordered in a simple list $\omega_1,\omega_2,\dots$. Instead they will need two indices like $\omega_{n,k}$. So I assume $Q'(\theta)=0$. That leaves us with the Bessel equation
$$P''(r)+\frac{1}{r}P'(r)+\omega^2 P(r)=0$$
Using the condition $P(0)<\infty$ we get
$$P(r)=J_0(\omega r)$$
And applying the BC $P(R)=0$ we get the normal frequencies and eigenfunctions $$\omega^{\text{circle}}_n(R)=\frac{\alpha_{0,n}}{R} \\ P_n(r)=J_0\left(\alpha_{0,n}\frac{r}{R}\right)$$

So, $\omega^{\text{square}}_1(L)=\omega^{\text{circle}}_1(R)$ exactly when
$$\frac{\alpha_{0,1}}{R}=\sqrt{2}\frac{\pi}{L} \\ \boxed{\frac{R}{L}=\frac{\alpha_{0,1}}{\sqrt{2}~\pi}\approx 0.541276}$$
The ratio of the next frequencies is
$$\frac{\omega^{\text{circle}}_2(R)}{\omega_2^{\text{square}}(L)}=\frac{\frac{\alpha_{0,2}}{R}}{\frac{2\sqrt{2}\pi}{L}}=\frac{L}{R}\frac{\alpha_{0,2}}{2\sqrt{2}~\pi}=\frac{\sqrt{2}~\pi}{\alpha_{0,1}}\frac{\alpha_{0,2}}{2\sqrt{2}~\pi}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\alpha_{0,2}}{\alpha_{0,1}}\approx \boxed{1.14771}$$

Comment: Superb, thanks!